# ROS indigo installation on Ubuntu 14.04.5 - packages too new?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ros, apt-get, aptitude

I'm trying to install ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.5 (fresh copy).
After having infinite issues with unmet dependencies and apt-get I tried to use aptitude instead. Trying to separately install the "unmet" dependencies I found that the issue was in packages being *too new* meaning that the version requested by ROS was older than the one that is installed.
Aptitude gives the ability to replace the newer packages with the older one that are requested..
Am I stupid or has someone encountered the same issues as I did?

Answer (score 0):

No its not the problem, as i have myself reinstalled the ROS indigo in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS few weeks before. U must have missed to follow some step given in the tutorial completely as a result u cant install the ros perfectly. I also used to get similar problems at first but, as i again tried it, it was successfully installed. so try again once, from starting.